# Modeling complex tree structure

Tags: java, object-oriented, domain-driven-design, domain-model, hibernate

After asking it in stackoverflow : [polymorphism-and-tree-structre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802725/polymorphism-and-tree-structre/38803148#38803148)
I came to a conclusion that I am not being specific and my question is not about any specific technology so I will try to rewrite it.
in the stackoverflow question I wrote about a grandparent/parent/child classes
in order for my question to be concise, this time I will be specific:
My real domain is of army simulator/game
the domain models are :
Corps -> Division -> Brigade which form sort of a tree structure
a Brigade parent must be a Division, a Division parent must be a Corps
a unit without a parent (except corps is not allowed)

furthermore the game is divided into players from three roles : corps general, divisional general and brigade general, each player need to select his managed unit according to his role - corps general selects a corps etc..

The ui for managing units looks like a tree in which you add, delete and edit the units:

- coprs

  - division

    - birgade

In my previous question the answer I got was to model it as

```
asbtact class Unit {  
   List<Unit> children;
   Unit parent;
}
```

which means I don't treat each unit type any differently
However, it doesn't fit quite well to my game, since it seems awkward to determine the unit type by state(doesn't have parent == corps for example), it allows for situations where a brigades parent is a corps which is not possible.
and I don't want a corps general to be able to select a brigade to manage just because somehow it wasn't assigned a parent and thus the game thinks its a corps.
to be more presice, I don't want to determine the units type by their location in the three, but rather the opposite, determine their location by their type.

---

**So my question is how do you think is the best way to model it in classes?**
I thought of a class of each type

```
interface Unit {
  Unit getParent();
  List<Unit>  getChildren()
```

}

```
   class Brigade implements Unit
   class Divison implements Unit
   class Corps implements Unit
```

Comment: I recommend to have a look into [this](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accountability.pdf) chapter from Martin Fowler's book "Analysis Patterns", it describes how to model organizational hierarchies.

Comment: @DocBrown that's shoud be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, the simplest model (in terms of pure structure) would be something like:

```
class Corps {
    final List<Division> children;
}

class Division {
    final Corps parent;
    final List<Brigade> children;
}

class Brigade {
    final Division parent;
}
```